# Discord.js V13 | Sticky Message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to create a sticky message for my server to keep everything at the bottom. I have tried a lot of different things but none of them worked.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message => { 
    if(message.channel === "") { // If someone sends a message in this channel, it gets triggered 
    let botcmd = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
        .setTitle("Bot Commands") 
        .setDescription("Description stuff ")

    // I want the bot to delete the previous message before sending the embed to avoid it deleting the new embed

    message.channel.send( {embeds: [botcmd] }) } })
})
```

How I want it to work:

Me : *sends message*

Bot : sends embed

Me: : *sends another message*

Bot : deletes old embed and sends new embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not an entirely clean solution, but I have tested this and it should put you on the right direction. I used `message.channel.messages.fetch()` method to fetch all the messages and used `.find()` to filter the messages based on author and channel id.

You can even set up a whitelist in an array to hold all the channels that have sticky messages enabled.

**Example of how I did it:**

```js
const stickyChannels = ["1031928905516470322"];
bot.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(stickyChannels.includes(message.channel.id)) {
        const fetchedMessages = await message.channel.messages.fetch();
        const stickyMessage = fetchedMessages.find(m => m.author.id === bot.user.id && stickyChannels.includes(m.channel.id));

        if(stickyMessage) {
            stickyMessage.delete().then(() => {
                message.channel.send("__ Sticky message__");

            }).catch(() => {});
        } else {
            // Force send a new message.
            message.channel.send("__ Sticky message__");
        }
    }
});
```

This is a general idea of how you can start using sticky messages in your Discord server. Note that you have to adjust this snippet to work in your own environment.