# How do I create a stickied message in Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, message

I've looked all over and I can't find a solution.

I'm using discord js using non-slash commands.

How could I make it so you have a message from the bot and if someone types in the channel the bot's message will get deleted and resent

I want to do this in a sense of a server request channel so you need to add the channel you want the command to run and what you want it to say:

e.g:

**Stickied Message**

Name:
Request Needed:
Approved By:

how could I program that? Thanks :) <3

I ahve googled online and can't see anything relating to this topic - maybe I'm not searching the right things?

Tried [Discord.js V13 | Sticky Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440647/discord-js-v13-sticky-message) but did not work

Comment: When you say "I tried but it didn't work", please provide the code to reproduce the problem and the full error message you receive.

Comment: 17.12 21:14:59 [Bot] bot.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
17.12 21:14:59 [Bot] ^
17.12 21:14:59 [Bot] ReferenceError: bot is not defined
17.12 21:14:59 [Bot] at Client.<anonymous> (/index.js:145:5)
17.12 21:14:59 [Bot] at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
17.12 21:14:59 [Bot] at MessageCreateAction.handle (/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:28:14)
17.12 21:14:59 [Bot] at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
17.12 21:14:59 [Bot] at WebSocketManager.handlePacket

Comment: I tried change bot to client but I'm not sure where to define bot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.